# Golang: Number of bits of an IP mask

Tags: go, ip-address

In Go, how do I get the number of bits of an IP mask like this: `10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0` => `24` bits maks.

It would be helpful to check if a mask is lower or greater than a certain number of bits (like if one wants to block all adresses greater than /24).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`net`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/) package has functions for getting the prefix size of a mask, the value used in [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation#CIDR_notation). The specific function for the bits is:

[func (m IPMask) Size() (ones, bits int)](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPMask.Size)

To get the bits, see the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    mask := net.IPMask(net.ParseIP("255.255.255.0").To4()) // If you have the mask as a string
    //mask := net.IPv4Mask(255,255,255,0) // If you have the mask as 4 integer values

    prefixSize, _ := mask.Size()
    fmt.Println(prefixSize)
}
```

**Output:**

24

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/twUUxzJ7FX)

**Ps.**

I assume you mean the bitmask 255.255.255.0

Comment: Great! I knew there was an easier way ([my attempt](http://play.golang.org/p/2hjumtMjS1))

Comment: @AdrianoP Your function works nicely though :). Size() will however return 0 instead of -1 (like in your function) when it is not in the canonical form; ones followed by zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward using the [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) for either IPv4 or IPv6.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    maskStr := "255.255.255.0"
    pref := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(maskStr).GetAddress().
        GetBlockMaskPrefixLen(true)
    fmt.Printf("prefix length for %s is %d", maskStr, pref.Len())
}
```

Output:

```
prefix length for 255.255.255.0 is 24
```